# How to use facet_grid() with geom_histogram()

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet

I tried using the `facet_grid()` for the first time. I plotted histograms with my own data, and the distribution seemed inaccurate when I counted the boxes manually on the graph. I replicated my code using the `mtcars` data, and the problem seemed to persist.

Here is the histogram produced by ggplot:

```
dfrm <- mtcars
dfrm$am <- factor(dfrm$am, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Automatic", "Manual"))
dfrm$vs <- factor(dfrm$vs, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("V-engine", "Straight-Engine"))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfrm, aes(x=dfrm[,"mpg"], fill=dfrm[,"am"], colour=dfrm[,"am"])) +
geom_histogram(colour="transparent", position = "identity", alpha=0.2, bins = 10) +
facet_grid(. ~ dfrm[,"vs"])
```

When I count manually on the histogram, I count:

- V-Engine, Automatic: 14
- V-Engine, Manual: 4
- Straight Engine, Automatic: 5
- Straight Engine, Manual: 9

This code counts how many of which exist in the actual data:

```
require(pastecs)
by(data=dfrm$am, INDICES = dfrm$vs,  table)
```

and the results are:

- V-Engine, Automatic: 12
- V-Engine, Manual: 6
- Straight Engine, Automatic: 7
- Straight Engine, Manual: 7

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to facet, or is this a bug?

I also did histograms with the base package to check if the results match, and those seem accurate when I count the boxes.

```
hist(mtcars[which(mtcars[,"am"]==0 & mtcars[,"vs"]==0),"mpg"], xlim=c(10, 35), col=rgb(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5), breaks=10)
hist(mtcars[which(mtcars[,"am"]==1 & mtcars[,"vs"]==0),"mpg"], col=rgb(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.5), breaks=10 ,add=T)
hist(mtcars[which(mtcars[,"am"]==0 & mtcars[,"vs"]==1),"mpg"], xlim=c(10, 35), col=rgb(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5), breaks=10)
hist(mtcars[which(mtcars[,"am"]==1 & mtcars[,"vs"]==1),"mpg"], col=rgb(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.5), breaks=10 ,add=T)
```

Thanks.

===EDIT===

The answer provided by bdemarest solves the problem. However, I am confused with the syntax that ggplot2 prefers, and how to put it inside a function.
Here is what I am going for:

```
myfunc <- function(varx, dfrm, facet = F){
  require(ggplot2)
  p = ggplot(dfrm, aes(x=varx, fill=am)) +
    geom_histogram(position="identity", colour="grey40", alpha=0.2, bins = 10)
  if(!is.logical(facet)){
    p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ facet)
  }
  return(p)
}
myfunc("mpg", mtcars, facet = "vs")
```

I tried with and without quotations, but couldn't get it to work.

=== EDIT2 ===

With the help of bdemarest in the comments, I made a lot of progress, but now the color fill fails, but only when the ggplot is inside a function

Here, this works perfectly:

```
facet = "vs"
p = ggplot(dfrm, aes_string(x="mpg", fill="am")) +
  geom_histogram(position="identity", colour="grey40", alpha=0.2, bins = 10)
if(!is.logical(facet)){
  p <- p + facet_grid(reformulate(facet, "."))
}
p
```

However, this does not:

```
myfunc <- function(varx, dfrm, facet = FALSE){
  require(ggplot2)
  p = ggplot(dfrm, aes_string(x=varx, fill="am")) +
    geom_histogram(position="identity", colour="grey40", alpha=0.2, bins = 10)
  if(!is.logical(facet)){
    p <- p + facet_grid(reformulate(facet, "."))
  }
  return(p)
}
myfunc("mpg", mtcars, facet = "vs")
```

The only problem here now is that the groups wont get colored accordingly. What am I missing?

Comment: For use inside a function, use `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`. The way your function is written, just change `aes` to `aes_string` to get it to work.

Comment: `aes_string` did it, but now the fill color broke for some reason I don't understand. It works when I write it outside a function, it does not when it is inside a function. Could you check my edit2? Thanks.

Comment: Latest problem is caused by `mtcars$am` being numeric, not factor. Either use the data.frame where `am` is already converted to factor (`dfrm`), or change `fill="am"` to `fill="factor(am)"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what caused this problem, but it seems to be solved by cleaning up and simplifying the ggplot code. In particular, ggplot2 is *not* designed to use column selection syntax such as `dfrm$am` or `dfrm[, "am"]` inside of the `aes()` function (nor in a formula expression like `facet_wrap(. ~ dfrm[, "vs"])`). Although these types of expressions often seem to work fine, in general they should be avoided.

```
library(ggplot2)

table(dfrm$am, dfrm$vs)
#           
#             V-engine Straight-Engine
#   Automatic       12               7
#   Manual           6               7

p = ggplot(dfrm, aes(x=mpg, fill=am)) +
    geom_histogram(position="identity", colour="grey40", alpha=0.2, bins = 10) +
    facet_grid(. ~ vs)

ggsave("hist.png", p, height=4, width=6, dpi=150)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the much more elegant way of counting frequencies with `table` rather than my code with `by`.

Comment: This fixed the problem in the sample code, works great. However, with the new syntax, I am confused how to put the ggplot code inside a function now. Could you have a look at my edits? Thanks!